# Why video is not displaying when i click on upload

Tags: django

Here uploaded video is not displaying on template name video.html. It is storing video in media but it is not displaying on template. Tell me what to do. Please anyone can help me out.

**views.py:**

```
def showvideo(request):
    lastvideo= Video.objects.all()
    form= VideoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context= {'lastvideo': lastvideo,
              'form': form
              }
    return render(request, 'master/video.html', context)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Video
        fields= ["name", "videofile"]
```

**templates:**
**video.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Upload Videos</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Video Uploader</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<br><br>
<video width='400' controls>
<source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ videofile }}' type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br><br>
</p>

</body>
<script>'undefined'=== typeof _trfq || (window._trfq = []);'undefined'=== typeof _trfd && (window._trfd=[]),_trfd.push({'tccl.baseHost':'secureserver.net'}),_trfd.push({'ap':'cpbh-mt'},{'server':'p3plmcpnl487010'},{'id':'8437534'}) // Monitoring performance to make your website faster. If you want to opt-out, please contact web hosting support.</script>
<script src='https://img1.wsimg.com/tcc/tcc_l.combined.1.0.6.min.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: try <sourcesrc="{{lastvideo.videofile.url}}" type='video/mp4'>

Comment: I have uploaded two videos but showing only one video. what to do now.  even i make changes in query to all instead of last, by doing this, it is only showing one video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**views.py:**

```
def showvideo(request):

    lastvideo= Video.objects.all()

    context= {'lastvideo': lastvideo }
    return render(request, 'master/video.html', context)
```

templates: video.html:

```
<video width='400' controls>
    <source src='{{ videofile.url }}' type='video/mp4'>
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have uploaded two videos but showing only one video. How to solve this

Comment: You have to use for loop to call each videos.